# Squiz Matrix vs Other CMS

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, content-management-system

According to:

http://intendance.com/2011/03/31/enterprise-content-management-open-source-squiz-matrix/

They have stated:

> Most other open source content
>   management systems options such as,
>   Drupal, Typo3, Mambo, Joomla rely on
>   their developers community for
>   extensions/addons maintenance and
>   upgrades with no guarantee that they
>   would continue to do so. While having
>   large community is great, the
>   enterprise approach provides a
>   framework you can extend to your own
>   uses. Most users of Squiz Matrix want
>   this flexibility. They not only want
>   to roll out websites that feels like
>   they came pre-implemented in their
>   CMS, but also editing interfaces and
>   processes that match their internal
>   work processes. And all this needs to
>   be done without writing server-side
>   codes. This one area is where Squiz
>   Matrix Excels compared to other
>   traditional open source CMS.

What does this mean and is it true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's essentially what I believe that paragraph means, if I translate (after reviewing their product)...

... starting with the last half of their paragraph first (because it'll make more sense that way)...

> People who manage a CMS (web site) want to be able to drag and drop cool plugins and add-ons to their site without having to learn how to code.  We can do that.  But you want your plugins to "feel" like they're actually part of your site (and not a tacked on after-thought).  Ours do.
>
> We're better than the other guys (like Drupal, Typo3, Mambo, Joomla) because... **Yes,** they also have all those cool plugins and add-ons that'll work for you (without coding)... **BUT**... Because they're "open source" and not "enterprise" you can't rely on them!  Who knows where those open source plugin developers will be in a year or two!

... this one sentence has no translation...

> *While having large community is great, the enterprise approach provides a framework you can extend to your own uses.*

If I were to try, it would sound something like this...

> A tip of the hat to open source for providing great support and development!  But "enterprise" is better because you can do whatever you want with it to make it better (like you **can** with Microsoft Word and you **can't** with OpenOffice).

Since you asked "is it true" I think that's a matter of opinion.  I would say, "no", if you choose a good open source CMS with a vibrant community.  I would say "yes" if you choose a sub-par tool with absolutely no community following ([like this one](https://www.squiz.net/))...

I will note also that it's a little difficult to gauge *exactly* how robust their plugin collection might be when you're left with this kind of jargon to figure it out: https://www.squiz.net/resources/integration-datasheet

Again, masterful writing!

Comment: love it ! masterful answer :-)

Comment: Squiz Matrix is rubbish, with 2 years of professional experience using it and developing advanced tools to make it work, I strongly advise against. Community based tools are more secure, have more plugins, better documentation and better support. Squiz mostly make their money by having a sales team that schmooze government and universities where the decision makers are ignorant of other options and make buying decision based on marketing hype instead of due research.